# Find the index value of coordinates in Python

Tags: python, arrays, coordinates

I have two arrays as:

```
A = [[1,0],[2,5],[6,7],[3,6],[7,6],[0,2],[4,1],[9,3],[6,5],[5,8]]

B = [[6,7],[0,2],[6,5]]
```

Firstly, I want to find the index value of A and then compare it to B and print the index value in B wrt A.
What I expect is:

```
[2, 5, 8]
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if an element in B appears twice in array A ?

Comment: I assume np.unique should remove the duplicate!

Comment: What should the result be for `B = [[0,2],[6,7]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to find the indexes of A which are also in B?

In that case:

```
C = [i for i in range(len(A)) if A[i] in B]
```

output:

```
[2, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = []
c = 0
for i in A:
   if i in B:
       d.append(c)
   c +=1
print(d)
[2, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it in this way, This might be a bit faster then 0(n^2)

```
mapper={}
for index,value in enumerate(B):
  mapper[f'{value}']=index
# print(mapper)

ans=[]
for index,value in enumerate(A):
  if f'{value}' in mapper.keys():
    ans.append(index)
print(ans)
```

ans > [2, 5, 8]